# Data appended to title tag after ajax call is not displaying on first hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Hi I have a ajax request that will fetch username, email and user_id. After ajax call success I am appending data using jquery to title tag, main issue I am facing is data getting appended but it is not showing on first attempt, but showing on second time hover.

Here is my code

```
function showProfile(i)
{
    var user = $("#user_id_"+i).html();
    var business = <?php echo $this->identity()->getBusiness()->getId() ?>;
    $.ajax({
        'url': '/user/account/external/profile',
        'type':'GET',
        'data':{
            businessId:business,
            userId:user,
        },
        'success': function (data) {
            var message = "Fullname : "+data.first_name+" "+data.last_name+" Email : "+data.email;
            $("#user_id_"+i).attr('title',data.first_name+'\n'+data.last_name+'\n' +data.email); 
        },
    });
}
```

Here is my html code which initiating ajax call

```
<a id="user_id_btn_'.$k.'" class="user_id_btn" onmouseover="showProfile('.$k.')" onmouseout="hideProfile('.$k.')"><span id="user_id_'.$k.'">'.$iResult[$k][4].'</span></a>
```

can anybody tell me how to improve this? I want to show data on hover on first attempt only not second.

Comment: The html doesn't seem to be valid `onmouseover="showProfile('.$k.')"`, What is it? a php string which has this html.

Comment: I guess `title` is being shown when you have mouse over it, it may not update unless you move your cursor and focus over it again!

Comment: You should have `title` attribute set `initially` when you are framing your markup in `php-loop`

Comment: everything is working fine data is coming and getting appended to title tag but as you said @Rayon it is showing when I mouse over twice, not on first attempt.

Comment: @Jai believe me html code is fine, no need to worry about it, can you tell me how to increase title tag performance or is there any other option to show data like hover?

Comment: @Rayon  Yeah I tried setting empty title="" for initial but still same result

Comment: @SudarshanKalebere, My suggestion was to assign title initially, not using `ajax`

Comment: Oh you mean I need to loop data while looping other info, but the thing is there too much of data and backend developeres dont want to load that initially, is there anything that I can use like span and then append value and do show n hide?

Answer (score 0):

`onmouseover="showProfile('.$k.')"` means, that when your mouse moves over this element, the function is called.
So if you would make an ajax request when the mouse hovers, the call starts and the data isn't loaded, when the browser processes the tooltip.
On second hover, the data is written from the first call.
Try to set the tooltip before hovering and then you don't need onmouseover because the tooltip is just shown when hovering ;)

Comment: but the data is coming from ajax call? I cant initialize data to title before hover, because its a table with many rows and developers will not change backend code

Comment: You can :)  
you can iterate through the table and add title like... "loading..." or something and start the calls for each row. then when the data loaded write it to the title-attribute